# Create a SQL Query with order by clause

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-order-by

I am creating a view with few tables and finally I want to order the data in the descending order.
when I use ORDER BY clause inside the create view statement, I get an error message saying ORDER BY clause can not be included inside a view. So that I used it with SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT with ORDER BY clause. But I have more than 100 rows in the output of my view.
How can I do it. Help me.

Create view statement without order by clause is as follows.

```
 CREATE VIEW VW_PF_GOALEVAL_REPORT AS 

 select GEV.EVAL_ID, EV.EVAL_NAME, GEV.FORM_ID,
 GEV.EMP_NUMBER,EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME, EMPS.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME AS SUP_NAME, EMPR.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME AS REV_NAME,
 GG.GGRP_ID, GG.GGRP_NAME, GG.GGRP_WEIGHTAGE,
 GEV.GOAL_ID, G.GOAL_DESC, GEV.GOAL_VERSION_NO,
 G.GOAL_WEIGHTAGE, G.GOAL_MANDATORY_FLG, G.TARGET_DATE,
 EG.RETME_ID,
 REE.RETMEITEM_GRADE AS EMP_RETMEITEM_ID, REE.RETMEITEM_DESCRIPTION AS EMP_RETMEITEM_DESC, GEV.GOALEVAL_EMP_RATING, GEV.EMP_COMMENT, 
 RES.RETMEITEM_GRADE AS SUP_RETMEITEM_ID, RES.RETMEITEM_DESCRIPTION AS SUP_RETMEITEM_DESC, GEV.GOALEVAL_SUP_RATING, GEV.SUP_COMMENT, 
 RER.RETMEITEM_GRADE AS REV_RETMEITEM_ID, RER.RETMEITEM_DESCRIPTION AS REV_RETMEITEM_DESC, GEV.SECOND_SUP_RATING, GEV.SECOND_SUP_COMMENT

 from PF_GOALEVAL GEV 

 LEFT JOIN  
 PF_EVALUATION EV
 ON GEV.EVAL_ID=EV.EVAL_ID

 left join 
 PF_GOAL G 
 ON GEV.GOAL_ID=G.GOAL_ID AND GEV.EMP_NUMBER=g.EMP_NUMBER AND GEV.EVAL_ID=G.EVAL_ID and GEV.GOAL_VERSION_NO=G.GOAL_VERSION_NO

 left join
 PF_GOAL_GROUP GG
 ON G.GOAL_TYPEID=GG.GGRP_ID

 left join 
 PF_EVALGOAL_GROUP EG
 ON GEV.EVAL_ID=EG.EVAL_ID AND GG.GGRP_ID=EG.GGRP_ID

 left join 
 PF_RETINGMETHODITEMS REE
 ON EG.RETME_ID=REE.RETME_ID AND GEV.GOALEVAL_EMP_RATING=REE.RETMEITEM_ID

 left join 
 PF_RETINGMETHODITEMS RES
 ON EG.RETME_ID=RES.RETME_ID AND GEV.GOALEVAL_SUP_RATING=RES.RETMEITEM_ID

 left join 
 PF_RETINGMETHODITEMS RER
 ON EG.RETME_ID=RER.RETME_ID AND GEV.SECOND_SUP_RATING=RER.RETMEITEM_ID

 left join 
 PF_EVALEMPLOYEE EVEMPS
 ON GEV.EMP_NUMBER=EVEMPS.EMP_NUMBER AND GEV.EVAL_ID=EVEMPS.EVAL_ID AND EVEMPS.APTYPE_ID=2
 left join
 EMPLOYEE EMPS
 ON EVEMPS.PERAPPRAISER_NUMBER = EMPS.EMP_NUMBER

 left join 
 PF_EVALEMPLOYEE EVEMPR
 ON GEV.EMP_NUMBER=EVEMPR.EMP_NUMBER AND GEV.EVAL_ID=EVEMPR.EVAL_ID AND EVEMPR.APTYPE_ID=5
 left join
 EMPLOYEE EMPR
 ON EVEMPR.PERAPPRAISER_NUMBER = EMPR.EMP_NUMBER

 left join
 EMPLOYEE EMP
 ON GEV.EMP_NUMBER=EMP.EMP_NUMBER

 left join
 PF_EVALAPPRAISER EVA
 ON gev.EVAL_ID = EVA.EVAL_ID
```

And finally I want to include

```
 order by gev.GOAL_VERSION_NO DESC
```

statement.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not saying 100 row, it is saying 100% which means all records

change the first select like this

```
 CREATE VIEW VW_PF_GOALEVAL_REPORT AS 

 select TOP 100 PERCENT GEV.EVAL_ID, EV.EVAL_NAME, GEV.FORM_ID,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Order By inside a view. If you use Top 100 Percent then you can ignore the error but you won't get the sorted result.

I can recommend you to use like this.

```
Select * from VW_PF_GOALEVAL_REPORT VW
order by VW.GOAL_VERSION_NO DESC
```

Suppose if you want to include the order by statement inside the view itself you can use Top 99 percent. Here you can get sorted results but there is a chance to miss few rows in your result set. Please use order by outside the view.